# How does an extension display info and warning messages in a theme-agnostic way?

Tags: extensions, blocks, best-practice, page-layouts

Not looking to display form validation errors, but more global messages like "Hurry quick -- offer ends in 4 hours" or "Currently there are 3 users online".

The question is not about how to generate the messages, but how to best present them in a way that will work nicely in any (or at least most) themes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Magento notification system](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-frontend/utilizing-magento-notification-system/). It should work anywhere anytime.

Notice

```
Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->addNotice(‘Notice message’);
```

Success

```
Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->addSuccess(‘Success message’);
```

Error

```
Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->addError(‘Error message’); 

Mage::getSingleton(‘adminhtml/session’)->addWarning(‘Warning message’);
```

(Admin only)

If this is not what you are looking for but the block in charge of displaying these messages, you need the [message block](http://makandracards.com/magento/10723-messages-and-global-messages-blocks).

Comment: Thanks for this. Problem with the above is that the message sometimes isn't visible until the next click. Any way around that?

Comment: Where are you setting the messages? If you set the message in a PHTML it will be shown on the next refresh, you should set it in a controller.

Comment: Not always possible to set all messages in the controller. I output them as they come up, e.g. when an error condition arises (like an Exception).